# Marcador de futbol c++

Tags: c++

ayuda porfa, debo que hacer una quiniela en c++ tipo del mundial con 4 equipos los cuales disputan 3 fechas, se debe solicitar los nombres de los 4 equipos primero, luego ingresar los marcadores de las 3 fechas algo asi:
(deben ser 3 rondas de marcadores)

marcadores
equipo 1:    equipo 2:
equipo 3:    equipo 4:

En esos nombres de equipo 1, 2, 3, 4 ya deben salir impresos los nombres que ingreso el usuario.

La pregunta es, como hago para que los equipos que ingresa el usuario en el case uno, se me impriman en el case 2 cuando ya va a ingresar el marcador?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
char equipo1 [20];
char equipo2 [20];
char equipo3 [20];
char equipo4 [20];
char equipos [29];



int main()
{
    int a, b;



        cout<< setw(30) <<"Selecciona una opcion \n";


   do {
        cout<< "1. Capturar equipos \n";

        cout<< "2. Registrar marcadores \n";

        cout<< "3. Ver estadisticas \n";

        cout<< "4. Reglas de la quiniela \n";

        cout<< "5. Salir \n";


        cin >> a;

    system("cls");

   switch (a)


{
    case 1: cout<< "Ingrese el nombre de los equipos \n";
            {
                cout<< "\nEquipo 1 \n";
                cin>> equipo1;
            }

            {
                cout<< "\nEquipo 2 \n";
                cin>> equipo2;
            }

            {
               cout<< "\nEquipo 3 \n";
               cin>> equipo3;
            }

            {
               cout<< "\nEquipo 4 \n";
               cin>> equipo4;
            }


            cout<< "presione una tecla para volver al menu" << endl;




    return 0;
    break;

    case 2: cout<< "Registre los marcadores \n";

    cout << equipo1 << ":\t";




    break;

    case 3: cout<< "Estadisticas \n";
    break;

    case 4: cout<< "Reglas \n";
    break;
}

    if (b=5)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    break;

}


   while (a != 5);
   system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Qué casualidad que haya [una pregunta parecida](/questions/559552)...

Comment: Hola, si, estaba viéndola, sin embargo no somos lo mismo, lo mio es un proyecto de la U, desarrollar la quiniela del mundial y lo que me cuesta es lo de los marcadores, saludos.

Comment: Es que ese no es el punto. En [es.so] se responden a preguntas _puntuales_, no se dan orientaciones ni tutoriales. Debes mostrar lo que has intentado, y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] para corregir tu pregunta.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añádenos más detalles de tu problema que estás intentando resolver.

Comment: Hola, asegura que tus preguntas se realicen con base a [ask], agrega lo que trataste o investigaste para evitar sea cerrada nuevamente esta pregunta (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/559552/como-hacer-una-quiniela-en-el-lenguaje-de-c), saludos.

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta y puse lo que llevo, gracias

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta?

Comment: La pregunta es, como hago para que los equipos que ingresa el usuario en el case uno, se me impriman en el case 2 cuando ya va a ingresar el marcador?

Comment: exactamente como lo estas haciendo.. cual es el problema con eso?

Comment: a la hora de ejecutarlo, no se me imprime el nombre del equipo en el case 2

Comment: Todos los que comentaron fue solo para criticar, linda comunidad

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: @SRM sí es una linda comunidad, ya que intenta que las preguntas y respuestas sean de calidad :) El contenido es moderado por todos. Además, muy probablemente no te hayan leído porque no llegan las notificaciones si no mencionas a un usuario con @. Pon lo que mencionaste como edición a tu pregunta. Tu problema debe ser _específico_, debes mostrar lo que has intentado para resolverlo (no basta con "cómo hago para"..., falta el "intenté con..."), y el error o problema que has tenido. De nuevo, lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que almacenar 4 equipos:

```
std::string equipos[4];
```

Y luego están los partidos. Un partido lo juegan dos equipos y cada uno consigue una puntuación.

```
struct Resultado {
  std::string local;
  std::string visitante;
  int marcador_local;
  int marcador_visitante;
};
```

Claro que también podríamos usar referencias para que los equipos que se enfrentan quedasen definidos automáticamente cuando el usuario los introduzca:

```
struct Resultado {
  std::string & local;
  std::string & visitante;
  int marcador_local = 0;
  int marcador_visitante = 0;
};
```

Podemos aprovechar también para dar un valor por defecto al marcador.

Y ahora necesitas almacenar 6 resultados, es decir, 3 jornadas con 2 partidos por jornada:

```
Resultado resultados[3][2];
```

Como la estructura usa referencias, el compilador nos obligará a inicializar el array:

```
Resultado resultados[3][2] = {
    { // Primera jornada
        { equipos[0], equipos[1] },
        { equipos[2], equipos[3] }
    },
    { // Segunda jornada
        { equipos[1], equipos[2] },
        { equipos[3], equipos[0] }
    },
    { // Tercera jornada
        { equipos[0], equipos[2] },
        { equipos[1], equipos[3] }
    }
};
```

Como ya hemos dado un valor por defecto al resultado de cada partido, al inicializar el array nos podemos centrar en dar valores únicamente a los campos de los equipos.

Como estos campos son referencias, da igual que esta inicialización la hagamos antes de conocer el nombre de los equipos. Los campos de los equipos se quedarán apuntando al elemento correspondiente del array de `equipos`.

Un ejemplo:

```
struct Resultado {
  std::string & local;
  std::string & visitante;
  int marcador_local = 0;
  int marcador_visitante = 0;
};

int main()
{
    std::string equipos[4];

    Resultado resultados[3][2] = {
        { // Primera jornada
            { equipos[0], equipos[1] },
            { equipos[2], equipos[3] }
        },
        { // Segunda jornada
            { equipos[1], equipos[2] },
            { equipos[3], equipos[0] }
        },
        { // Tercera jornada
            { equipos[0], equipos[2] },
            { equipos[1], equipos[3] }
        }
    };

    equipos[0] = "Equipo 01";
    equipos[1] = "Equipo 02";
    equipos[2] = "Equipo 03";
    equipos[3] = "Equipo 04";

    for (int jornada=0; jornada<3; jornada++)
    {
        std::cout << "Jornada " << jornada+1 << '\n';
        for (int partido=0; partido<2; partido++)
        {
            Resultado const& resultado = resultados[jornada][partido];
            std::cout << "  " << resultado.local << " vs " << resultado.visitante << "  " << resultado.marcador_local << " - " << resultado.marcador_visitante << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando [aqui](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DtqeZbblNqDpQ6st)

Ya solo faltaría introducir los resultados de los partidos